# json mime-type on 2003 server issue

Tags: json, web-config, iis-6, mime-types, windows-server-2003

Here is my issue:

- I have a solution working on a 2003 server with iis 6
- And every time I deploy the solution I have to configure the MIME type on the iis.

I have implemented this in my web.config, but it doesn't seem to work properly.

```
    <staticContent>
  <remove
            fileExtension=".json" />
  <mimeMap
            fileExtension=".json"
            mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
```

Is there a global way of setting this up?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution to the problem, add this code on top of the other and it worked.

```
 <system.web>
    <staticContent>
      <remove
                fileExtension=".json" />
      <mimeMap
                fileExtension=".json"
                mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.web>
```

The issue was that the `<system.webserver>` not allways works on 2003 server, therfore the `<system.web>` was needed also.